# Extjs 4.2 create a global data error handling that will get overrides by implementations

Tags: javascript, extjs, error-handling, extjs4

I would like to create a generic error handling for my REST API called from my JavaScript code.

whenever there is an HTTP status greater the 200 I would like to show an alert to the client with the error message.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
// sets the default application settings.
    setAppDefaultsSettings: function () {
        Ext.Ajax.timeout = 120000;
        Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', this.onRequestException, this);
    }, // eo setAppDefaultsSettings

    /// fires when an error occurs on an HTTP request.
    onRequestException: function (conn, response, options, eOpts) {
        switch (response.status) {
            case 401: return Nip.utils.handle401Error(conn, response, options, eOpts); // Unauthorized
            case 403: return Nip.utils.handle403Error(conn, response, options, eOpts); // Forbidden
            case 404: return Nip.utils.handle404Error(conn, response, options, eOpts); // Not Found
            case 405: return Nip.utils.handle405Error(conn, response, options, eOpts); // Method Not Allowed
            case 408: return Nip.utils.handle408Error(conn, response, options, eOpts); // Request Timeout
            case 409: return Nip.utils.handle409Error(conn, response, options, eOpts); // Conflict
            case 410: return Nip.utils.handle410Error(conn, response, options, eOpts); // Gone
            case 500: return Nip.utils.handle500Error(conn, response, options, eOpts); // Internal Server Error
            case 501: return Nip.utils.handle501Error(conn, response, options, eOpts); // Not Implemented
            case 502: return Nip.utils.handle502Error(conn, response, options, eOpts); // Bad Gateway
            case 503: return Nip.utils.handle503Error(conn, response, options, eOpts); // Service Unavailable
            case 504: return Nip.utils.handle504Error(conn, response, options, eOpts); // Gateway Timeout
            default: return Nip.utils.handleGeneralError(conn, response, options, eOpts);
        }
    }, // eo onRequestException
```

This works great the problem is that I cannot override this behavior on implementations that require different handling.

How can I state that on one of my proxy's a 404 return should not invoke the generic error handling for example...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [suspendEvent](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-suspendEvent) together with resumeEvent. Try to suspend the `requestexception` before sending the ajax request, and resume just afterwards.
An issue you could run into when using this, is when different ajax calls are called at the same time, certain that require the event others that don't.

Another, maybe cleaner approach is to create extend `Ext.Ajax`, and create a new class `Nip.Ajax`, that includes your custom exception handling, and then in your code, you call `Ext.Ajax`or `Nip.Ajax` depending on the requirement for request exception handling.